# Show alert if Chrome/Firefox extension is not installed

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox

I have a website with a lot of TV channels. Most of them without web player so they need a Chrome/Firefox extension like "Native HLS Playback".

Chrome:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/native-hls-playback/emnphkkblegpebimobpbekeedfgemhof

Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/native_hls_playback/?src=recommended

Is there any way to show a message or open the extension website automatically if detects that it's not installed?

Thank you.

Comment: I presume in javascript you try to play the feed? will something return false or throw an error if the user doesn't have the extension?

Comment: A simple alert would be enough. Something like "Native HLS player not installed"

Comment: Sorry, I was asking if you use javascript to initiate the starting of playback, and if so, do you get any errors if they do not have the plugin?

Comment: Could you post the javascript?

Comment: I open the url directly. Something like:

HTML:
<a href="http://url.com/stream.m3u8" target=">

PHP:
header("Location: http://url.com/stream.m3u8");

Comment: In that case, I don't really know a solution... You could try looking into `chrome.runtime.connect()` at least for the chrome users. Take a look [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-connect)